# Java generic wildcard capture "?" restrict forbids modifying a value

Tags: java, list, generics, wildcard, addition

I've got this:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("ok");
    list.add("123");
    List<?> list1 = list; // What is the point of disallow modify?
    list1.add("xyz");//compile error
    List list2 = list;
    list2.add(123);//runtime exception
```

It's odd that:

```
List<?> list1 = list; // What is the point of disallow modify?
list1.add("xyz");//compile error
```

Why it doesn't allow me to write an element even type matches? I suppose the  makes "list1" readonly, without write permission?

How to understand this compilation error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You shouldn't use raw types at all. They're only there for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<?>` can only be used as reference declaration. It's a way of telling compiler that it can hold any type of list but I won't add anything to list.

```
public void printMyList(List<?> mylist){
  mylist.forEach(item->System.out.println(item)); // works fine
  mylist.add("abcd"); //compilation error
}
```

Compiler prevents this because there's a chance you might end up putting a wrong type in the list.

Modifications are sometimes allowed in case of wildcard if used along with super:

```
public void printMyList(List<? super Car> mylist){
  mylist.add(new Toyota()); //works fine
}
```

This tells the compiler to accept list type of Car or any super type of Car. Adding a Car or a Toyoto or a Ford which are subtype of Car is perfectly fine in this case.

Comment: You can add `null` to the `List<?>`.

Answer (score 3):

`List<?>` means it is a list, but we don't know at compile time what's in it.

While we may be able to prove in this case that it's a `List<String>`, most of the time we won't know whether it's a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Animal>`.  And of course, adding an `Integer` to a `List<String>` is rather dangerous, so Java will stop it at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

`List<?>` means the `List` contains an unknown type, and it could be any type at run time. So  you can not assign an `List<String>` to it at compilation stage, it's not type safe.

Let's suppose you are allowed to add elements to it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> list1 = list;
list1.add("123"); // it's ok for an list to and string "123", but it's not type safe for list1 to add string "123", since it contains an unknown type at run time.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'readonly' when typecasting. The only thing you do is changing the generic type meaning the compiler will complain about differences. If we break down the code you have two different result because of the interpretation by the compiler.

First:

```
List<?> list1 = list;
```

What you did is 'down-cast' a `List<String>` to a wildcard typed `List<?>`. This means that anything will throw a compile error, simply because it cannot know what the wildcard should/will be. (thats why adding a String resulted in a compile error).

In your second example you used a 'raw-type':

```
List list2 = list;
```

A raw-type doesn't care about generic types, and so does the compiler in that case. Thats why there was no exception thrown as every typed-parameter simply defaults to `Object` (which is the baseclass of every class in java). Adding a integer (`123`) which is also a Object is therefore perfectly legal for the compiler. However on runtime an Exception is thrown since the types dont match. For this exact reason is it consideren a bad-practise to use raw-types, as these kind of problems can be hard to find/solve.